# customise saml attributes Azure AD

Tags: single-sign-on, entra-id, saml

I have configured SAML SSO against a new app in my Azure Console. I have proven it authenticates using simplesamlPHP. I am trying to add/adjust the attributes that are passed back with the SAML token.

[Test App in Azure Active Directory Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzAiP.png)
[SimpleSAMLPHP confirmation of authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cZ2w.png)

This documentation (and several other sources) says to just click on 'View and edit all other user attributes'
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization

But I cannot for the life of me see where this option is in the console, can someone show me a screenshot of where to access the attributes for my application?

[No Custom Attributes option on App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWcqr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Azure AD premium to do this. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

Comment: This definitely seems like the answer. I will get the premium and check. Many thanks.